# Keep getting an undefined is not an object (evaluating 'date.substr') error on my desktop

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, widget

[The error I'm receiving.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGxGp.jpg)

Hey everyone I need some help. So I am using a tool called Ubersicht. It allows you to create widgets on your Mac desktop using .coffee script files. The one that has the error is supposed to be a calendar to show me my upcoming events. This is the code for it.

```
# Bash command to pull events from icalBuddy
# Set +2 to how many days you want to show
# icalBuddy has more functionality that can be used here
command: "/usr/local/bin/icalBuddy -n eventsToday+2"

# Update is called once per hour
refreshFrequency: "1h"

# CSS styling
style: """
top: 10px
top: 35%
right: 73.5%
color: black
font-family: SF UI Text
background-color rgba(white, 0.2)
padding 15px
border-radius 5px
width: 270px

div
    display: block
    color white
    font-size: 14px
    font-weight: 450
    text-align left

#head
    font-weight: bold
    font-size 20px

#subhead
    font-weight: bold
    font-size 16px
    border-bottom solid 1px clear
    padding-top 6px
    padding-bottom 3px
    """

 # Initial render for heading
 render: (output) -> """
<div id="head"> Upcoming Events </div>
"""

# Update when refresh occurs
update: (output, domEl) ->
lines = output.split('\n')
bullet = lines[0][0]
newarray = []

# Copy lines to new array, ignoring all location lines
# This allows for easier tokenizing as array format is consistent
for line in lines
    if ( line.indexOf("location") == -1 )
        newarray.push(line)

# Check that events actually exist or not
if ( lines.length < 2 )
    if ($(domEl).text().indexOf("No Events") == -1)
        $(domEl).append(""" <div id="subhead"> No Events </div> """)
    return

# If events exist, print subheadings and data
for i in [0...newarray.length-2]

    # Print today subheading
    if ( newarray[i+1].indexOf("today") != -1 )
        if ($(domEl).text().indexOf('Today') == -1)
            $(domEl).append("""<div id="subhead"> Today </div> """)
    # Print tomorrow subheading
    else if ( newarray[i+1].indexOf("tomorrow") != -1 )
        if ($(domEl).text().indexOf('Tomorrow') == -1)
            $(domEl).append(""" <div id="subhead"> Tomorrow </div> """)
    # Print later subheading
    else if ( newarray[i+1].indexOf("after") != -1 )
        if ($(domEl).text().indexOf('Day After Tomorrow') == -1)
            $(domEl).append(""" <div id="subhead"> Day After Tomorrow </div>     """)
    # Only print event newarray, starting with a bullet point
     if (newarray[i][0] == bullet)
        # Tokenize icalBuddy output string
        name_and_calendar = newarray[i].split('(')
        name = name_and_calendar[0].substr(1)
        # Trim length of name field
        if ( name.length > 25 )
            name = name.substr(0,25) + "..."
        # Trim date and format output
        if ( ':' in newarray[i+1] )
            date = ((newarray[i+1].split("at"))[1])
            date = "at" + date.substr(0,9)
        # If its an allday event, date field is empty
        else
            date = ""
        # Cleanse output from icalBuddy
        calendar = name_and_calendar[1].replace(')','')
        # Combine all fields
        final = calendar + " - " + name + date

        # Add this HTML to previous, only if it doesn't already exist
        if ($(domEl).text().indexOf(final) == -1)
            $(domEl).append("""
            <div>
                #{final}
            </div>
            """)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could it be that `date = ((newarray[i+1].split("at"))[1])` is `undefined` because `newarray[i+1]` doesn't contain `"at"`?

Comment: @le_m Maybe. So what would I do to fix it?

Comment: No idea, that depends on the content of `newarray` and what you want to do if it doesn't contain `"at"`.